# Mathematica's evaluation of nested summations

Tags: symbolic, summation

As suggested there, here is a copy of [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186383/mathematicas-evaluation-of-nested-summations) I've posted on Math.Stackexchange.

Suppose we want to count the number of instructions executed by the following Python code:

```python
sum = 1
print("1 instruction first")

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(i,n-3+1):
        sum = sum + i + j 
        print(f"3 instructions here : {i}, {j}")
```

Trivially, for `n = 5` (for example), we can count 10 instructions (1 instruction for the first line, and 3 instructions to compute the sum):

```python
1 instruction first
3 instructions here : 1, 1
3 instructions here : 1, 2
3 instructions here : 2, 2
```

Let us try to evaluate this mathematically. The number of instructions is given by the following expression: $1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n-3} 3$

Mathematica (or at least WolframAlpha) evaluates this expression as $\frac{3}{2} (n - 5) n + 1$... which is equal to $1$ for $n=5$. Indeed this closed formula doesn't take into account the fact that by convention, an empty sum (when the start index of the variable is greater than the upper bound) sums to 0.

So, three questions:

1. did I make a mistake in my reasoning?
2. is there a bug in Mathematica (I mean, with respect to what I exposed there)?
3. how to correctly express the for loops with sums in that case?

Comment: Please show the actual Mathematica code you used.

Comment: As I said, I just used WolframAlpha ; the formula I used is : `1 + sum_(i=1)^n sum_(j=i)^(n-3) n`

Comment: @Greg82 Wolfram|Alpha is not Mathematica and the idea that Mathematica would do the same thing as W|A is a misconception. In fact, W|A is off-topic here.

Comment: @Szabolcs, sorry for this misconception, I followed the suggestion given in math.stackexchange to post it here (are WolframAlpha and Mathematica engines really different, by the way?).  Edit: Answers given below seem to confirm that Mathematica has the same behaviour for my question

Comment: Another convention to consider: Assume the user’s input is valid (upper limit $\ge$ lower limit). Your result is what most people want from W|A (I’d bet). I wouldn’t consider it a bug in W|A, but questions about W|A are off-topic here. Note 1: The standard convention violates the property, ignoring assumptions on limits, $\sum_{i=a}^cx_i-\sum_{i=b}^cx_i=\sum_{i=a}^{b-1}x_i$, for example when $a=1,\ b=-2,\ c=5$. Note 2: The Python `for` convention corresponds to a different summation one, namely $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i:=x_1+\cdots x_n$, which is better mathematically (and why Python adopted it)

Comment: I answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187065), but briefly: `1 + Sum[3, {j, 1, n - 3}, {i, 1, j}]` is what you should have evaluated instead.

Comment: Yes, Mathematica does behave in the same way in this case so this was definitely worth asking/answering here. In the future, please do provide the Mathematica code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I would consider this a bug, although not a surprising one.

---

This is how one would normally write this sum in Mathematica:

```
1 + Sum[3, {i, n}, {j, i, n - 3}]
```

To keep things simple, I will use the following simplified version:

```
Sum[1, {i, n}, {j, i, n - 3}]
(* 1/2 (-5 n + n^2) *)
```

As you observe, the result is not correct for symbolic `n`. For an explicit integer `n`, it does give the correct result as it performs the summation explicitly:

```
With[{n = 5},
 Sum[1, {i, n}, {j, i, n - 3}]
]
(* 3 *)
```

Most likely, Mathematica computes this sum as

```
Sum[Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}], {i, n}]
```

The result of the inner one is

```
Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}]
(* -2 - i + n *)
```

This result is valid only when `i <= n-3`, as you also note in the question. This behaviour is normal and documented for `Sum`, though perhaps difficult to notice on the documentation page. There is an option to ask `Sum` to generate explicit conditions for when the result is valid:

```
Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[-2 - i + n, -i + n ∈ Integers && n >= 3 + i] *)
```

Thus, I would consider the result of `Sum[1, {j, i, n-3}]` acceptable, and the "wrong" result from the explicitly nested `Sum[Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}], {i, n}]` to be "user error". However, I am not happy with the result from `Sum[1, {i, n}, {j, i, n - 3}]`, as there is no explicit nesting here. Personally, I would consider this a bug, while realizing that it may not be an easy to fix bug ... Note that in this "nested" sum, `i <= n-3` will *always* be violated.

---

The workaround is in the spirit of @flinty's answer: we explicitly nest two `Sum`s and manually put conditions on the inner one. I would have hoped that the following works, but unfortunately it does not (the outer sum does not evaluate). Perhaps that makes sense as the `ConditionalExpression` is not *zero* when the condition is not satisfied.

```
Sum[
 Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}, GenerateConditions -> True],
 {i, n}
]
```

One possible solution is an explicit [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

```
Sum[
 Piecewise[
  {{Sum[1, {j, i, n - 3}], i <= n - 3},
   {0, True}}
  ],
 {i, n}
 ]
```

[image]

Another solution, which seems easier to me, is

```
Sum[Boole[i <= n - 3], {i, n}, {j, i, n - 3}]
```

[image]

These results are correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference you need to account for with a `Piecewise` so that it doesn't incorporate the inner sum when your `range(i,n-3+1)` is empty:

```
result[n_] := 1 + Sum[
  Piecewise[{{Sum[i + j, {j, i, n - 3}], i < n - 3 + 1}}, 0]
  , {i, 1, n}]
```

Mathematica can now generate a correct closed form for symbolic $n$ given by `result[n]`:
$$
1+\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(n^3-7 n^2+16 n-12\right) & n>3 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
This matches up to the results of:

```
test[n_] := (sum = 1; For[i = 1, i < n + 1, ++i,
   For[j = i, j < n - 3 + 1, ++j,
    sum += i + j;
    ]
   ]; sum)
```